# Weird border shows after page standing for a while in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, frontend

I've got a weird issue only in iOS.

My HTML5 page shows alright in the beginning, but let it sit for a while (likely 3 minutes, doing nothing during this period), some elements will generate unexpected grey right-border:

[image]

I think it's a bug of webkit, anything I can do to hack it?

Comment: maybe something wrong of css? try to use * {outline: 1px solid green;}

Comment: @TomFan I don't think so, it behaves well in the beginning and the issue only happens in iOS. I did try `outline: 0` but it resolved nothing.

Comment: * {outline: 1px solid green;}, it means to make everything having outline. Therefore, you may find the mistake in css.